# PHP: How can i make so non valid users gets another zipfile?

Tags: php

I am really new at php and i came across this code.

Right now it checks for the hwid of a user and grants permission to a zip file if the hwid is in the valid users.
How can i make so the non valid users gets another zipfile to download?

Code:

`

```
$VALID_USERS = [
    'BB12313-25DC-5132-BCEA-B23123123123', 
    ''
];

$IS_REQUEST_ALLOWED = false;

if(!isset($_POST['hwid']) && !isset($_GET['hwid'])) { die(); }

$USER_HWID = '0';

if(isset($_POST['hwid'])) { 
    $USER_HWID = $_POST['hwid'];
} else { 
    $USER_HWID = $_GET['hwid'];
}

$USER_HWID = trim($USER_HWID);
$USER_HWID = strtoupper($USER_HWID);

foreach($VALID_USERS as $USER) {
    $USER = strtolower($USER);
    $HWID = strtolower($USER_HWID);

    if($HWID === $USER) {
        readfile('./ZIPFILE.zip'); die();
    }
}
```

`

Comment: use else condition in above code

Answer (score 0):

Assuming other code functions properly, your `if` clause at the end should look like this:

```
if($HWID === $USER) {
    readfile('./ZIPFILE.zip'); die();
} else {
    readfile('OtherFile.zip'); die();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After you compare $HWID === $USER, offer a different file in the ELSE added below.

```
foreach($VALID_USERS as $USER) {
    $USER = strtolower($USER);
    $HWID = strtolower($USER_HWID);

    if($HWID === $USER) {
        readfile('./ZIPFILE.zip'); die();
    } else { //not a valid user
       readfile("./invalid_file.zip");die();
    }
}
```

Note that this will give "invalid_file.zip" to anyone who doesn't meet the criteria ($HWID===$USER) (maybe, see below).

Also, die() is rather a nasty way to exit (it doesn't even tell the user why it's leaving ...).

Please also take a look at your $VALID_USERS array.  Surely you don't mean to have a null value in there?

Finally, what about the case of someone else who isn't null or "BB12313-25DC-5132-BCEA-B23123123123"?

You might wish to reconsider the use of this code.

Comment: Look closely at his loop, adding else isn't going to do what you think it does.

Comment: I also looked at his array.  The code is generally rather poor to begin with.  Why do you suppose NULL is up there?

Comment: Agreed question could be much better.  Even with null up in his array (assuming it is not his way of shortning it for example), you will want to take into account that the array has more then one value.  Adding the else inside the loop means only the first array value is ever checked.

Comment: I just came across this code my knowledge of php is zero, i had already tried with adding } else { to it and it doesnt work, forgot to mention it in first post.

I just want a code that checks for hw id in a list and if the user is not in there they should be given another file.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your entire foreach loop with this one if block.  Since you are keeping your VALID_USERS in an array, you can use [in_array()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) to quickly check if you user is there, the loop is unnecessary.

This:

```
foreach($VALID_USERS as $USER) {
    $USER = strtolower($USER);
    $HWID = strtolower($USER_HWID);

    if($HWID === $USER) {
        readfile('./ZIPFILE.zip'); die();
    }
}
```

Becomes:

```
if (in_array($USER_HWID, $VALID_USERS, true)) {
    readfile('./ZIPFILE.zip'); die();
} else {
    readfile('./SomeOtherZIPFILE.zip'); die();
}
```

You will also notice that the 3rd paramter to in_array() has been set true in this example.  This enables strict type comparison, to match the original codes '===' check.